# Mismatch in extracting names using web scraping beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all doctors names from the below link using the program below. In the web page there are 13 doctors but I am able to extract only 10 out of 13. I tried many ways to extract but I don't get the desired results. Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import urllib.request
import re
base_site = "https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=DL&Otn1=798&Ic1=127&Ftg=33014+Bad+Driburg&Ftg_e=&Lng=36"
response = requests.get(base_site)
response.status_code
html = response.content
html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
with open('TK_33014_Bad_Driburg_LXML.html','wb') as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))

divs = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "card dl"})

headings = [div.find('a').text for div in divs]
headings
```

Results of the headings:

```
['Frau Dr. med. Chrxxxx Balduhn',
 'Frau Dr. med. Bixxx Stecher',
 'Frau Dr. med. Urxx Kuhlmann',
 'Herr Dr. med. Anxxx Rasche',
 'Herr Dr. med. Matxxx Sablotny',
 'Frau Dr. med. Chrixxxe Rübsam',
 'Herr  Acxxx Peter',
 'Frau Dr. med. Hexxx Schulze',
 'Herr Dr. med. Gexxx Sander',
 'Herr  Johannes Blxxx']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the class 'card-body' instead of 'card dl'.

```
divs = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "card-body"})

headings = [div.find('a').text for div in divs]

print("\n".join(headings))
```